# Bing ads conversion goals

Tags: javascript, php, magento, ads, bing

I'm trying to add in the bing conversion script in to my magento website.

I know I need to add this code below to the header of the website

```
   <script>(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"XXXXXXX"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");</script><noscript><img src="//bat.bing.com/action/0?ti=XXXXXXX&Ver=2" height="0" width="0" style="display:none; visibility: hidden;" /></noscript>
```

**** Removed bing id for XXXXX ******

But I need to pass a variable conversion value in the checkout success page so would I add the following script below to the success page?

```
    <script>
window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
window.uetq.push({  'gv': '<?php echo $order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>'});  // Pass the computed revenue 
   </script>
```

Also does the above code script look fine for the final magento price to get passed over to the main script in the head of every page?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

to add script to header, you could add the following in your local.xml:

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="core/text" name="bing.conversion">
    <action method="setText">
        <text>
            <![CDATA[<script>(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"XXXXXXX"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");</script><noscript><img src="//bat.bing.com/action/0?ti=XXXXXXX&Ver=2" height="0" width="0" style="display:none; visibility: hidden;" /></noscript>]]>
        </text>
    </action>
</block>
```